# add css file with file system - fs - in nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, html, css

I'm trying to use nodejs to make a website. I added a `fs` module and use an external file to present `index.html`. That's ok. But I have a css file to style the `index.html`, named `index.css` and it does not work.

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
 <title>Some title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test/index.css">
</head>

<body lang="pt-br">
 <img src="_image/logonp.png" id="imglogologin">
 <div id="divlogin">

  <form name="login">

   <input type="text" id="idnome" name="nnome" size="20" maxlength="30" placeholder="Nome" autofocus onkeydown = "if(event.keyCode == 13)document.getElementById('idsenha').focus()"><br>

   <input type="password" id="idsenha" name="nsenha" size="20" maxlength="20" placeholder="Senha" onkeydown = "if(event.keyCode == 13)document.getElementById('idbutton').click()">

   <input type="button" id="idbutton" onclick="verifylogin(this.form)" value="Login" >

  </form>

 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Files:

- index.html (ProjectFolder/test/index.html)
- test.js    (ProjectFolder/test.js)
- index.css  (ProjectFolder/test/index.css)

My `test.js` file:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(request, response){
  if(request.url == '/'){
    fs.readFile('test/index.html', function(err, html){
      response.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
      if(err) response.write('index nao encontrado');
      response.write(html);
      response.end();
    });
  }
  else if(request.url == '/second'){
    response.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
    response.write("<h1> second page </h1>");
    response.end();
  }
  else {
    response.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
    response.write("<h1> incorrect page </h1>");  
    response.end();
  }
}).listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('server started');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add bunch of code as below to response with your css file:

```js
if (request.url == '/test') {
   fs.readFile('test/index.css', function(err, css) {
      if (err) {
        response.writeHead(404)
        response.write('index nao encontrado')
        response.end();
      };
      response.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/css' });
      
      response.write(css);
      response.end();
   });
}
```